# Link not working for Vimeo examples

Tags: android, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

The [link](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/blob/v2.0.0/example) to the examples given [here](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java) on GitHub is not working.

Can anyone provide an alternate to this or a link to examples for playing Vimeo videos in Android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that! The correct example link is here:

https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/tree/develop/example-java-android